# Clone detection algorithm

Tags: algorithm, clone

I'm writing an algorithm that detects clones in source code. E.g. if there is a block like:

```
for(int i = o; i <5; i++){
doSomething(abc);
}
```

...and if this block is repeated somewhere else in the source code it will be detected as a clone. The method I am using at the moment is to create hashes for lines/blocks and compare them with hashes of other lines/blocks in the same source to see if there are any matches.

Now, if the same block as above was to be repeated somewhere with only the argument of doSomething different, it would not be detected as a clone even though it would appear very much like a clone to you and me. My algorithm detects exact matches but doesn't detect matching blocks where only the argument is different.

Could anyone suggest any ways of getting around this issue? Thanks!

Comment: ... uhh, just curious but... why do you want to do that?

Comment: This link would probably help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294447/how-can-i-find-source-code-copying Though it's C++, software that can be used on various languages has been supplied.

Comment: @quasiverse: I would imagine for refactoring?

Comment: To optimise source code by removing code duplication. There are probably tools that exist that do this but I would like to create my own algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a super-simple way, which might go too far in erasing information (i.e., might produce too many false positives): replace every identifier that isn't a keyword with some fixed name. So you'd get

```
for (int DUMMY = DUMMY; DUMMY<5; DUMMY++) {
  DUMMY(DUMMY);
}
```

(assuming you really meant `o` rather than `0` in the initialization part of the `for`-loop).

If you get a huge number of false positives with this, you could then post-process them by, for instance, looking to see what fraction of the DUMMYs actually correspond to the same identifier in both halves of the match, or at least to identifiers that are consistent between the two.

To do much better you'll probably need to parse the code to some extent. That would be a lot more work.

Comment: This + trim and remove newlines and you are on the way to find some dupes.

Comment: Yo would probably put the loop-variable in another set (i.e. DUMMY1) because it is initialized inside this block.

Comment: Oops I meant 0. I think this is a good idea...I'm worried it will incorrectly flag clones though e.g. if a bunch of lines did not have any keywords, they would be detected as clones.

Comment: Only if the structure was the same -- same sequence of tokesn apart from different identifier names. For instance, `foo(a,b,c);` would be different from `foo(a,b);`.

Comment: @Philipp T., I'm not sure you can actually make that work. Consider, e.g., that you want to catch the same block of code even if it sometimes occurs inside a `for`-loop and sometimes not.

Comment: You would perhaps abstract away definitions to arrive at a canonical definition of (variables defined inside block, v. defined outside block, block-code).

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're going todo something else then you're going to have to parse to code at least a bit. For example you could detect methods and then ignore the method arguments in your hash. Anyway I think it's always true that you need your program to understand the code better than 'just text blocks', and that might get awefuly complicated.